# Google Website Translator: TypeError when clicking "Contribute" button

Tags: javascript, google-translate

We use the standard Google Website Translator gadget on our site http://ut.no.

The "Contribute a better translation" feature has stopped working. When you click on the "Contribute" button, you get this javascript error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a[hd][H]')
```

in "element_main.js" injected by Google.

This worked fine several weeks ago. Are anyone else having this problem, or is it only us?

After some testing, I fond out that it's the meta tag from Google that's part of the problem. 
Removing  the "google-translate-customization" meta tag makes the suggestions work, but the suggestion never gets delivered to our Website Translator page.

Comment: IMHO if you want i18n on your website just implement proper translations, don't give the user a false sense that the website can be displayed in their language while it's just a makeshift translation.

Comment: I have this problem as well. I have been trying different jQuery versions. No luck so far. Can you post more info, like JS versions and Google Translate JS link?

Comment: @DDDD we use the code generated by Google at http://translate.google.com/manager/website/settings

Comment: @Bard sorry I noticed you posted the link to your site so I can see all the JS. I don't think were going to get much help. I have been searching for help for awhile. Currently I am thinking there is JS conflict with versions on our sites. I see your using a widget, have you tried removing it just to test?

Comment: @DDDD I have made a quick test file (plain html + Google Website Translator gadget code) locally and on Dropbox, and I get the same error.

I have also sent feedback to Google, but no reply yet.

Comment: @Bard I have tried switching to the jQuery 1.11.1, no luck. I also reported the error. :/

Comment: After some testing I fond out that it's the meta tag from Google that's part of the cause. 
Removing  the "google-translate-customization" meta tag makes the suggestions work (I think...), but the suggestion are not sent to the Website Translator page.

Comment: @DDDD our Website Translator has started to work again. But it looks like Google is planing to kill the corrections feature! There is a warning on our manager site saying: "Website Translator Corrections won’t be available after March 16, 2015."