# When using google translate, how do I approve user-contributed translation improvement suggestions?

Tags: google-translate

I have implemented Google Translate for a [single page in our site](https://www.radiology.wisc.edu/fileShelf/contrastCorner/gadcalc.php), and have native speaker users who have tried to contribute a better translation.

According to the (very old) [google translate blog](http://googletranslate.blogspot.com/2012/05/now-you-can-polish-up-googles.html), I should be able to approve these translations somewhere. I am the site owner, but where should be logging in or looking for a console to approve the user contributions?

I found [Bard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4314845/bard)'s [response to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248433/google-website-translator-typeerror-when-clicking-contribute-button) suggesting "Website Translator Corrections won’t be available after March 16, 2015."

If that's true that may be the issue. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: have you tried this link https://translate.google.com/toolkit/list?source=webtrans#tms